# Make mobile slide into viewport when scrolled

Tags: css

I am coding a WP theme, and have a problem:

When I click the hamburger menu before scrolling down the page, my mobile menu slides in perfectly. However, if I scroll down the page, the mobile menu doesn't slide into view (I have to scroll back up to see it).

I've tried a number of things (overflow-y: scroll), but can't seem to get it to work! What can I do? Javascript?

HTML/PHP:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-light">
        <div class="container">    
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/img/fullLogo.png" class="fluid-img pull-md-left" id="navLogo">
                </a>

                <div class="hidden-sm-down">
                    <?php 
                    $mobileMenu = array(
                        'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
                        'container' => false,
                        'theme_location' => 'mobile_menu',
                        'menu_class' => 'desktop-nav',
                        'container_id' => 'desktopNavContainer', 
                    );
                    wp_nav_menu( $mobileMenu );
                    ?>
                </div>

                <a>
                    <button type="button" id="hamburger" class="pull-right hidden-md-up">
                        &#9776;
                    </button>
                </a>
        </div>
        </nav>
    <div id="mobileMenu">
        <button type="button" id="mobileMenuCloseButton" class="pull-right">
            &#735;
        </button>
        <div id="mobileNavWrapper">
            <?php 
                $mobileMenu = array(
                    'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
                    'container' => false,
                    'theme_location' => 'mobile_menu',
                    'menu_class' => 'mobile-menu',
                    'container_id' => 'mobileNavContainer', 
                );
                wp_nav_menu( $mobileMenu );
            ?> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
/******** NAVIGATION ************/

#mobileMenu{
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10000;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.95);
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#mobileNavWrapper{
    margin-bottom: 70%;
}

#mobileMenuCloseButton{
    font-size: 2em;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: -25px;
    right: 9%;
}
```

and finally, the JS:

```
/* ----------- MOBILE MENU APPEAR --------------- */
    $('#hamburger').click(function(){
        console.log('got it');
        $('#mobileMenu').slideDown(400);
    });

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 600){
            $('#mobileNav').addClass('menuScrolled');
        } else{
            $('#mobileNav').removeClass('menuScrolled');
        }
                     });
```

Comment: tried to use position:fixed?

Comment: I'll make you a quick mark up for a mobile navbar, give me a sec.

Comment: Your #mobileMenu should be position:fixed; in your css  and not relative or absolute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I made built you a quick mock up of a fixed header so you can see how the navbar sticks to the top.

HTML:

```
<nav class="mobile-header">
      <ul>
        <!-- I'll leave this empty for now --> 
      </ul>
      <div class="hamburger">
        <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
.mobile-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/zsawaf/pen/xOWONq

Code in action ^

Comment: Hey @zsawaf! My menu sticks to the top (it's fixed), but the problem is where the menu slides down.

When the page hasn't been scrolled, the menu slides down fine. But when the user scrolls down and then clicks the hamburger (which is still visible), the menu doesn't slide down into the viewports (it stays at the top, off screen). If you wanna look at it, my site is www.kleanir.com

Comment: All you have to do is make the menu position fixed. Updated codepen to reflect changes.

Comment: Ahhh I see! Perfect, it works great, thanks @zsawaf!!